# Adding hive and hadoop jars to IntelliJ project

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, intellij-idea, hive

I've been recently trying to run some unit tests locally (Spark-Scala project), and encountered the following

```
ClassNotFound java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities when creating Hive client using classpath: 
Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.
```

Where in an IntelliJ project is one supposed to include these jars? E.g., `hive` is working fine from terminal, but IntelliJ seems to require some additional configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't add to the IDE. Rather you'd use tools like Maven or Gradle

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, I'm using maven as a build system yes. How does one add jars there?

Comment: add to the pom.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Maven, it's necessary to add the dependency for `hive` in the pom.xml

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

After adding it, reload the project via the Maven tool window:

[image]